# PyTorch DataLoader output format

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm playing with Diffusion Models using the code from [here](https://github.com/cloneofsimo/minDiffusion/blob/master/train_cifar10.py).
I'm trying to use a custom set of images, from Hugging Face.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datasets import load_dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


dataset = load_dataset("jiovine/pixel-art-nouns-2k", split="train")

tf = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]
)

dataset = dataset.with_transform(tf)
dataset.set_format(type="torch", columns=["image"])

data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True, num_workers=8)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 6, figsize=(16, 4))
for i, image in enumerate(dataset[:6]["image"]):
    axs[i].imshow(image)
    axs[i].set_axis_off()
```

With this piece of code, I can properly visualize the images:

[image]

When I try to call the training, I get an error though:

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
from mindiffusion.unet import NaiveUnet
from mindiffusion.ddpm import DDPM

def train(data_loader: DataLoader, n_epoch: int = 100, device: str = "mps") -> None:
    """
    Train Diffusion Model.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data_loader: data loader.
    n_epoch: number of epochs.
    device: device to run the training on.
    """

    ddpm = DDPM(eps_model=NaiveUnet(3, 3, n_feat=128), betas=(1e-4, 0.02), n_T=1000)
    ddpm.to(device)

    optim = torch.optim.Adam(ddpm.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

    for i in range(n_epoch):
        print(f"Epoch {i} : ")
        ddpm.train()

        pbar = tqdm(data_loader)
        loss_ema = None
        for x, _ in pbar:
            optim.zero_grad()
            x = x.to(device)
            loss = ddpm(x)
            loss.backward()
            if loss_ema is None:
                loss_ema = loss.item()
            else:
                loss_ema = 0.9 * loss_ema + 0.1 * loss.item()
            pbar.set_description(f"loss: {loss_ema:.4f}")
            optim.step()

        ddpm.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            torch.save(ddpm.state_dict(), f"./ddpm_weights.pth")

train(data_loader)
```

[image]

This is the first time I'm using PyTorch. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic, but I haven't found what. I've inspected the `data_loader` using `next(iter(dataloader))`, and it prints something like the following, which follows the same pattern as if I use the original CIFAR10 dataset.

```
{'image': tensor([[[[213, 216, 225],
           [213, 216, 225],
           [213, 216, 225],
           ...,
           [213, 216, 225],
           [213, 216, 225],
           [213, 216, 225]]]], dtype=torch.uint8)}
```

I'm also not sure why the normalization hasn't happened when I call `next`.

Comment: Have you tried using enumerate, in order to have 2 values to unpack from the progress bar (index, data) ? 
`pbar = tqdm(enumerate(data_loader))`
and then:
`for i, x in pbar:
...
`

Answer (score 1):

The original code uses `CIFAR10` dataset, where each item returned from `dataloader` has [2 elements](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10.html#torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10.__getitem__), `image` and `label`. The original code only uses `image` of the 2 elements, so the code was like this,

```py
        # (x, _) unpacks from (image, label)
        for x, _ in pbar:
            optim.zero_grad()
```

In contrast, in the dataset `jiovine/pixel-art-nouns-2k`, the format for an item is set to `image`, with `dataset.set_format(type="torch", columns=["image"])`. As a result, each item from the dataloader would be of one element, and it could not be unpacked using `x, _` in the for loop.

One possible fix is to change `for x, _ in pbar:` to `for x in pbar:`.